# Cargo run results in No such file or directory (os error 2)

Tags: rust, operating-system, rust-cargo

I'm on a MacBook Pro with M2 CPU if that matters - `cargo run` results in:

```
cargo run                                                                                              
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.05s
 Running `target/debug/somebinary`
Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I've tried starting a new project just to reproduce it, but to no avail - `cargo run` works just fine! I tried disabling my tests to see if they did anything, but no. I've tried looking into file permissions and file type, but that also didn't work.

```
file ./target/debug/somebinary                                                                             
./target/debug/somebinary: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Yet, if I try to execute it, I get os error 2.

```
./target/debug/somebinary                                                                                  
Error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I'm completely stuck and out of ideas! What the hell is wrong here?!

Here's my `cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "somebinary"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.4.8", features = ["derive"] }
ctrlc = "3.4.1"
rand = "0.8.5"
tempfile = "3.8.1"
walkdir = "2.4.0"

[[test]]
name = "somebinary-test"
path = "tests/mod.rs"
```

My source code is in `src/main.rs` with another file `src/csv.rs`, whereas the test lives in `tests/mod.rs`. I'm wondering if naming conventions by any chance might result in this obscure error?

My file structure:

```
somebinary
┣ src
┃ ┣ csv.rs
┃ ┗ main.rs
┣ tests
┃ ┣ data
┃ ┃ ┣ bad-file.csv
┃ ┃ ┗ good-file.csv
┃ ┗ mod.rs
┣ .gitignore
┣ Cargo.lock
┣ Cargo.toml
┣ README.md
┗ test_data.csv
```

Comment: That's really odd.

1. Is the file really called `somebinary` or does it have a name that could somehow be special (unusual encoding, etc.)?
2. Have you double-checked that you have the right to access/execute that file?

Comment: It might be OS X being "helpful" in preventing that unknown/unverivied application from running. OSX does have a track record of doing that. Albeit in the past that resulted in different errors.

Comment: I remember seeing this kind of error on MacOS sometimes. I honestly do not remember what the exact problem was, but I have a gut feeling that it may have been missing dynamically linked libraries or something like that. Just something you could have a look at.

Comment: You're trying to run an x86 binary, do you have Rosetta installed? (I vaguely remember running into weird errors around this before.)